# clear a topic to make it 'unpublished'

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, gmapping, amcl, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a project where I want to be able to launch the turtlebot gmapping demo immediately after the amcl demo. I do not want to add to a map that I've already been navigating, instead I want to clear the map that was used by the amcl navigation demo and start a new one. The problem I have is that the /map topic seems to hold the values that the navigating demo was using. I don't want to quit ros and start it over again. What I was hoping was that there was some way to clear the map and proceed from there.

How does one clear a topic to the state of emptyness or the state of not being published at all? Can this be done programmatically? Does this make sense?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133576/clear-a-topic-to-make-it-%27unpublished%27/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A topic doesn't hold anything. What does is the node that publishes that topic. Either the node has a functionality to clear/unpublish a topic or you simply kill the node that has been publishing so far.

In your case amcl probably uses the map_server. As you want to run gmapping afterwards, you can just bring that down, i.e. kill the map_server, and probably also amcl. If you start gmapping then, no other map messages should be flying around.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0